# Library Host audio OSX

Tags: python, macos, audio, midi

Currently running a project in python which create a bunch of midi files, then map them to the OSX Host audio unit.

We've been using pyau, which worked fined with some library, but won't work now with kontakt5 and library like Shevannay (also not maintained since along time ago).

I've been over github, the python page music, google over the last week, to find a project up to date, that would fill our need (read midi file, create an host, load vst and presets and export it in any audio format).

If the library isn't in python that doesn't matter, our python script are writting midi file, so i'm okay to do read and map it to a host in any other language.

But all answer i could get were rewritting an host in c++ using juce, I don't think i actually need to writte my own code for that, they are probably people that have done that in a better way that i could do it.